# How Do I Create a Startup for No-ip?

Tags: boot, script

I am on Raspbian. I want no-ip to startup everytime it boots. 
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: A critical detail: Does `no-ip` require a GUI to function? Or is it terminal-based?

Comment: Create a systemd Unit file.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a general Linux question as NO-IP clearly [document their api](https://www.noip.com/integrate/request) and have full install details for the Linux client at [this page](https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client/)

Personally I would check your router to see if that does an update - lots of them do and you need to be in the set-up to set the port forwarding.

Once you have followed these instructions, then their support states:

> Read the README file in the no-ip-2.1.9 folder for instructions on how to make the client run at startup. This varies depending on what Linux distribution you are running.

Assuming the client continues running I would look to start it via a simple cron job set for @reboot or look to create a service that restarts if it ends.  The document referenced above should help.

If Raspbian is not mentioned look to the Debian instructions.

Answer (score 1):

What I've got is a script that runs every three minutes using a line in crontab

```
*/3 * * * * /home/dougie/dnso.sh
```

This ugly bash script gets my public IP address using the OpenDNS service then drives the No-IP updater. It logs every IP address when it changes (I've got a record of 303 addresses since 8th Jan 2015). You'd need to kickstart it with `echo "192.168.3.14" > ipaddr.saved.txt` so that the first `head` command doesn't fail.

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDaddr=$(head -1 /home/dougie/ipaddr.saved.txt)
IPv4=$(dig +short myip.opendns.com \@resolver1.opendns.com | grep -v -e '^$' || echo "0.0.0.0")

IPaddr=$(printf "\"$IPv4\"")

if [ $IPaddr == '"0.0.0.0"' ]; then
  exit 20
fi

if [ $OLDaddr != $IPaddr ]; then
  NOW=$(date +"%d/%m/%Y, %T,")
  printf "$NOW New address found\r\n"
  echo -e $NOW$IPaddr >> /home/dougie/ipaddr.log.txt
  echo $IPaddr | tee /home/dougie/ipaddr.saved.txt
  printf "\r\n"
  printf "\r\n"

  curl -s -o - -u myname@example.com:myredactedpassword "http://dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update?hostname=darkside&myip=$IPv4"
  printf "\r\n"
  ~/python/pubIP.py | mail -r "dougie@example.co.uk" -s "New IP Address" mygmail+email@gmail.com

fi
```

That very crude python program called at the bottom sends an email when my IP address changes (so it doesn't matter where in the world I am when it changes - I can still logon to home (even if my No-IP update fails)). I've included it to show how to get your public IP address using httpbin.org in python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import socket

ipj = urlopen('http://httpbin.org/ip').read()
ipd = ipj.decode('utf-8')
#print(ipd)
ip = json.loads(ipd)
#print(ip)
ips = str(ip['origin'])
#print(ips)

#ip1, ip2 = ips.split(',')

print(ips)

name, alias, addresslist = socket.gethostbyaddr(ips)
print (name)
```

Those two programs are commandline (no GUI) so you should be able to run them at boot up time with no problems.